# Запись данных используя подзапрос

Tags: sql

Мне необходимо в @list таблицу внести данные из нескольких таблиц с определенным списком условий(@SearchParams@)

```
DECLARE @list table(
[SerialNum] NVARCHAR(50)
,[Description] NVARCHAR(50)
,[Place] NVARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO @list (
[SerialNum]
,[Description]
,[Place]) 
SELECT v.[SerialNum]
       ,v.[Description]  
       ,l.[Place] 
FROM [Equipment].[dbo].[Ent_Equipment] v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM [Equipment].[dbo].[Ent_LabVerification]  
                 WHERE [Actual]='1') AS vr 
ON v.Id=vr.Id_Equipment 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM [Equipment].[dbo].[V_Location] 
                 WHERE [Actual]='1') l 
ON v.Id=l.Id_Equipment WHERE v.[Id_Category]='B724FAF6-1EAB-4004-A8F7-8E9236AB3911' 
AND @SearchParams@
```

Но при выполнение запроса возникает ошибка
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS
из-за того, что запрос выдает несколько полей и больше одной записи.

Как необходимо построить запрос, чтобы выполнились условия при выборке? Вообще реально такое?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: приведенный выше запрос не должен вызывать такой ошибки. проблема где то внутри @SearchParams@ и вы уверены что в запрос можно подставлять часть _текста_ условия в виде переменной не используя при этом возможности динамических запросов (sp_executesql)

Comment: А зачем вам подзапрос, который называется vr?
Что будет без него?

Comment: msi, для vr в @SearchParams@ тоже имеются условия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Избавьтесь от подзапросов. Они ни к чему, могут только наоборот повредить плану.

```
SELECT v.[SerialNum]
       ,v.[Description]  
       ,l.[Place] 
FROM [Equipment].[dbo].[Ent_Equipment] v 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Equipment].[dbo].[Ent_LabVerification] AS vr 
  ON v.Id=vr.Id_Equipment AND vr.[Actual]='1'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Equipment].[dbo].[V_Location] AS l 
  ON v.Id=l.Id_Equipment AND l.[Actual]='1'
WHERE v.[Id_Category]='B724FAF6-1EAB-4004-A8F7-8E9236AB3911' 
AND @SearchParams@
```

Судя по тексту ошибки у вас проблема где-то внутри @SearchParams@
Привидите его текст.